# Quicksilver Large Type

Tags: bash, macos, quicksilver

You know how you can make Quicksilver display massive large type on your screen?  (By Hitting . then typing free text, select View Large Type under actions and hit Enter).

Well, does anyone know of a way to do that programmatically?  Also, is quicksilver even required or is it built into OS X?  I would love to be able to trigger that from bash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no special sauce here. It's putting up a window with the text you type displayed in a large font. Duplicating the effect in a Cocoa app is trivial.

Comment: but there's no built-in way to do it from terminal?

Comment: No. There's no built-in way to show any arbitrary window from the Terminal as far as I know.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with Applescript, so therefore you can so it in bash with the osascript command:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Quicksilver" to show large type "Hello, world."'
```

I think that "Large Type" was previously available in the services menu, but I don't see it in Snow Leopard. I might be wrong about that. A similar feature is found in Address Book -- right click on a telephone number.

Answer (score 1):

If you like to know how they exactly implemented it, you can look at the global method QSShowLargeType in their source here:

https://github.com/quicksilver/Quicksilver/blob/master/Quicksilver/Code-QuickStepInterface/QSLargeTypeDisplay.m

Answer (score 1):

You could do it inside your browser with [large-type.com](http://large-type.com/):

```
$ open http://large-type.com/#YourText
```

Answer (score 0):

It is confirmed to be fixed in the next release (after b56a7). Better keep an eye on the download area:
http://code.google.com/p/blacktree-alchemy/downloads/list

Comment: I think your answer has nothing to do with this question.

Comment: I disagree. The feature he asked about will be implemented in the next version. Since Quicksilver has a script component it is very well possible to set this up properly the way asked.

Comment: so your answer assumes QuickSilver is required then, correct?

Comment: The question was about Quicksilver, so I guess yes. Hate down-votes :/