# Quicksilver Large Type in XCode

Tags: xcode, macos, quicksilver

I'm new to XCode and looking to do something similar to Quicksilver's "Large Type" in my XCode OSX (not iOS) app.

I'd like to write a function that I can call with a single string, and it would display that string like Quicksilver would - leaving it on top of the screen until the user clicks or presses a key.
If someone could give me some pointers on how to achieve this, that would be great.

(Note: I've read this question: [Quicksilver Large Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1234686), and am under the impression that I should create a window (maybe with a panel on which I update the text) and display the window and close it again, etc. I'd rather just write a quick function that will do this though - I don't want a main menu or window controls displayed.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for: http://www.markdouma.com/developer/BlackBorderlessWindow.zip

More info on
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4447132/347353

It's not a simple function to call (thankfully - otherwise Mac apps would be full of this rather annoying *feature**) - but at least you don't have to create it from a scratch.

---

* The only valid use for this behavior is arguably the same that Apple & QuickSilver do use it for.